# Find value of $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{2x+\sqrt{4x^2+3x-2}}{3x+2}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{2x+\sqrt{4x^2+3x-2}}{3x+2}$$
I got an answer of 4/3 however the answers I was given is none of the above.
any explaination to the solution

Comment: How did you come to $4/3$? Note that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ so $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$ if $x$ is negative.

Comment: If you had sketched the graph of the numerator, you would have seen at a glance that the correct limit is zero. Geometry !

Answer (score 3):

Set $-\dfrac1x=h\iff x=-\dfrac1h$

$$4x^2+3x-2=\dfrac{4-3h-2h^2}{h^2}\implies\sqrt{4x^2+3x-2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{4-3h-2h^2}}{|h|}$$

Now as $h\to0^+,h>0\implies|h|=+h$

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\dfrac{2x+\sqrt{4x^2+3x-2}}{3x+2}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{-2+\sqrt{4-3h-2h^2}}{2h-3}=\cdots=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Divide numerator and denominator by $x$ but remember that $x<0$ and:

$$
a \sqrt{b}=\mbox{sign}(a)\sqrt {a^2b}
$$
where $\mbox{sign}(a)$ is the sign of $a$ ( here it's your mistake).